# Is there any way to make anaconda smaller?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ubuntu, anaconda

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Anaconda 2, which takes over 5 gb disk space. Is it normal to take such large space, or I can make it smaller by removing some unnecessary folders?

P.S. Some commands such as "conda clean" have been used, I just wonder if there are some repeated modules installed...

Comment: Use [miniconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html) and only add the packages you need (numpy -> mkl; qt and co. are the typical *big* libs). Don't touch those folders without knowing what you are doing!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 10):

I have seen anaconda accumulate lots of garbage package caches and tarballs. To delete caches, tarballs and lock files which are not used and reduce a little bit the space used, you can try:

`conda clean -a`

Answer (score 2):

It depends what do you really want to use.

Install miniconda instead of Anaconda and then install required packages 1 by 1 using

> conda install

this will definitely reduce the size. :)

Comment: Doesn't answers the question in any way. There is no mention of installing `jupyter` or `spyder` in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Important to note that conda is a package/environment manager, which can build an anaconda environment.

More often than not, they are considered as one and the same which is untrue.

If you want to simply use conda, the package/environment manager and not have the entire anaconda environment packaged with it, you can install miniconda -
https://conda.io/miniconda.html- which gives you the conda application, without the bloat* of the entire scientific stack of anaconda.

miniconda will have a far smaller footprint, and then using conda to create specific (streamline/smaller) environments for usage will also be more storage-efficient.

Make the separation between conda and anaconda in your thinking, and it should make things easier to understand.

**not quite fair, it is not that it is bloat, it is just overkill for 99% of users*